# Shell script grep standard output file empty

Tags: linux, shell, grep, tshark

I wrote this little script to write tshark results in a file, but with grep, log file remains empty

```
tshark -i usbmon1 -T pdml -Y usbccid -V |grep 'field name="data"'>/home/pi/logcard/log-$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%T)
```

Without this part
/home/pi/logcard/log-$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%T)
The capture works well

Did I do something wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Probably the output is given through stderr, so you'll need to redirect to stdout: `tshark ... |&  grep ...`.

Comment: Can you provide below detail
1) You are running on which shell ?   
2) is removing $(date +%d-%m-%Y-%T) writing to log file or not. I think %T might be causing the issue as it will give backslash in output

Comment: Have you already tried putting `2>&1` before the redirection (see fedorqui's comment)?

Comment: I'm using /bin/bash, the file is created with the date but there is nothing inside. I will try    2>&1